# Supabase next-auth prisma CredentialsProvider

Tags: prisma, next-auth, supabase

How do I use next-auth in combination with supabase and prisma?

I can see from the documentation that both, supabase and prisma have adapters with next-auth but I don't understand how they fit together.

For my app I will need to use a simple Email/Password authentication schema. No social logins - in fact the user can't even create his/her own account, it will be created by the admin.

I understand that I can do that in the CredentialsProvider of next-auth but my problems arises with the integration in supabase. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdYQ9fF-hz4&t=702s which explains how to setup a different Schema for next-auth in supabase. The problem I am facing it that I seemingly can't get these tables with `npx prisma db pull`

How does all of this fit together?

Comment: If you want a simple email login, you can just use Supabase to achieve it. No need to use next auth or Prisma.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be missing is baselining your database. When using existing tables, such as those that an initial Supabase project provides, you should follow this quick guide before doing any migrations etc: https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/add-to-existing-project/relational-databases/baseline-your-database-typescript-postgresql